# PDFsharp Unrecognized Characters Display as "?"

Tags: vb.net, unicode, pdfsharp

I'm trying to convert the contents of a combobox to text in PDFsharp for printing. Unfortunately, all the "✓" become "?". I've tried using Unicode but nothing changes.

Here's what I'm using;

```
For Each cbx In Crt.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)
        If cbx.Visible = True Then
            Using Gra As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(Pg(Doc.PageCount - 1))
                Dim tf As Layout.XTextFormatter = New Layout.XTextFormatter(Gra)
                Dim x = cbx.Location.X * WScale
                Dim y = cbx.Location.Y * HScale
                Dim w = cbx.Width * WScale
                Dim h = cbx.Height * HScale
                Dim Brush As XBrush = New XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(cbx.BackColor.ToArgb))
                Dim xrect As New XRect(x, y, w, h)
                Gra.DrawRectangle(Brush, xrect)
                Dim options As XPdfFontOptions = New XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always)
                Dim xFt As New XFont("Times New Roman", 7, XFontStyle.Regular, options)
                tf.Alignment = Drawing.Layout.XParagraphAlignment.Justify
                tf.DrawString(cbx.Text, xFt, XBrushes.Black, xrect, XStringFormats.TopLeft)
            End Using
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Emojis show as little squares (not ?) in my asp 4.5.2 UI. :(  e.g. " It's MEGA" - Same problem I expect though, here in 2022 June.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character "✓" probably is not included in the "Times New Roman" font you select and therefore it does not show.

Only use characters included in "Times New Roman" or use an appropriate font if you need "✓".

Comment: I've tried changing it from "Times New Roman" to "Microsoft Sans Serif" which is the font the tick appears on. I've also tried several other fonts and nothing works. Instead the ? becomes a box

Comment: The check mark you posted here (Unicode 2713) appears in "Segoe UI Symbol", but not in "Times New Roman" and not in "MS Sans Serif". I don't have "Microsoft Sans Serif" on my computer.